# Command line argument into a shell script conversion?

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have a command line argument that I need to convert into a shell script. Can someone explain me how to this?

If it is something simple like below, also, how to take care of lower and upper cases here?

`cat * |perl -ne '{chomp; print "$_\n" if ($_=~ /MAR-|-MAR/|/JAN-|-JAN/|/FEB-|-FEB/|/APR-|-APR/|/MAY-|-MAY/|/JUN-|-JUN/|/JUL-|-JUL/|/AUG-|-AUG/|/SEPT-|-SEPT/|/OCT-|-OCT/|/NOV-|-NOV/|/DEC-|-DEC/|/dec-|-dec/|/Aug-|-Aug/|/Jan-|-Jan/|/Sept-|-Sept/)|/Feb-|-Feb/|/Mar-|-Mar/|/Apr-|-Apr/|/May-|-May/|/Jun-|-Jun/|/Jul-|-Jul/|/Oct-|-Oct/|/Nov-|-Nov/}'|more`

Comment: It looks like you have two separate topics here. Can you split them into separate questions?

Comment: You never have to use `cat` to feed input to Perl: Just put your arguments after the code: `perl -e'code here' *`. Although with a glob like `*` you would likely have to do some sanity checks to avoid processing directories and such.

Comment: Also, your regex has a grievous error: `/` is a meta character inside your regex, and you have not escaped it. Normally, you would get an error like `Search pattern not terminated`, but you have actually terminated yours by accident. This: `$_=~ /MAR-|-MAR/|/JAN-|-JAN/` means this: `$_ =~ m/MAR-|-MAR/ | $_ =~ /JAN-|-JAN/` -- two expressions with the `|` [bitwise OR operator.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or).

Answer (score 1):

To make your test case insensitive, add `i`. Example:

```
 if ($something =~ /re/i) {
```